# Запуск одной программой другой программы и передача ей значения

Tags: c++, ubuntu, pipes

Я написала программу, которая считывает от пользователя две строки, сохраняет их в неименованный канал и запускает вторую программу, которая будет работать с этими строками. Вопрос: как можно передать значение pipes[1] второй программе?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{ 
int buf[6];
int pipes[2];
int mas[6]; 
pipe(pipes);

char time[9] = ""; 
int j = 0;
cout << "Enter the first time value in hh.mm.ss format\n";
cin >> time;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if (int(time[i]) >= 48 && time[i]<58) 
    {
        mas[j] = 10* int(time[i]-48) + int(time[i+1] - 48);
        j++;
        i++;
    }
}
cout << "Enter the second time value in hh.mm.ss format\n";
cin >> time;
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    if (int(time[i]) >= 48 && time[i]<58) 
    {
        mas[j] = 10 * int(time[i] - 48) + int(time[i + 1] - 48);
        j++;
        i++;
    }
}

write(pipes[1], mas, sizeof mas);
read(pipes[0], buf, sizeof mas);
close(pipes[0]);
close(pipes[1]);

char parametr1[] ="server";
char parametr2[]= "/";
char *args[]= { parametr1, parametr2, NULL };
pid_t pid=fork();
if (pid==0)
{
execve ("server", args, NULL);
}
else
{
int status;
waitpid (pid, &status, 0);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: вот пример [как `ls -l | sort -k9 | less` команду на С поверх POSIX вызовов реализовать](https://gist.github.com/zed/7540510). В с++ стоит внешние команды с помощью библиотек более высокого уровня запускать (`popen()`, [QProcess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20901974/4279))

Comment: В потомке, после `fork()` и перед `execve()` сделать ваш pipe  стандартным вводом программы с помощью `dup2()`

Comment: И write лучше выполнять уже после fork()